# How to fetch records from another table in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `tblEmployee` and `tblTarget`.
This is my SQL query:

```
select EmpCode,E.TM_Name, CurrentTarget, CreatedDate,RankOrder,A.PreviousTarget from(
select EmpCode, CurrentTarget, CreatedDate,RankOrder,T.PreviousTarget from (
    Select
        EmpCode, CurrentTarget, CreatedDate,PreviousTarget,
        Rank() over (partition by EmpCode order by CreatedDate desc) RankOrder
    From tbl_Target
) T WHERE RankOrder=1)A
left join  tblEmployee E on A.EmpCode=E.TM_Emp_Id
```

This is what I am getting and it is perfect.

```
EmpCode        TM_Name         CurrentTarget CreatedDate             RankOrder     PreviousTarget
-------------- --------------- ------------- ----------------------- ------------- --------------
20078          kaul            60            2018-07-11 05:05:03.687 1             50
56042          Bob             40            2018-07-11 05:05:03.687 1             20
56079          Alice           30            2018-07-11 05:05:03.703 1             30
56080          Sikon           50            2018-07-11 05:05:03.703 1             40
56094          Ssohy           35            2018-07-11 05:05:03.703 1             20
```

I am getting only those Employee results which are present in `tblTarget`. While employee who do not have target are not displaying.
Though I want them to be displayed with 0 `CurrentTarget` and 0 `PreviousTarget`.
I want output like this:

```
EmpCode        TM_Name         CurrentTarget CreatedDate             RankOrder     PreviousTarget
-------------- --------------- ------------- ----------------------- ------------- --------------
20078          kaul            60            2018-07-11 05:05:03.687 1             50
56042          Bob             40            2018-07-11 05:05:03.687 1             20
56079          Alice           30            2018-07-11 05:05:03.703 1             30
56080          Sikon           50            2018-07-11 05:05:03.703 1             40
56094          Ssohy           35            2018-07-11 05:05:03.703 1             20
101            Joe             0             2018-08-12 05:05:03.687 1             0
102            John            0             2018-08-12 05:05:03.687 1             0
103            Sid             0             2018-08-12 05:05:03.687 1             0
104            Manous          0             2018-08-12 05:05:03.687 1             0
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Try using RIGHT JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the direction of the `left-join`. You need all employees, even the ones that do not have a matching row in the targets, so you either switch the order of the tables and make the `Employee` table the left one (which I did in the code below) or you change your join to a `right join`:

```
select EmpCode, e.TM_Name, isnull(CurrentTarget, 0) CurrentTarget, CreatedDate, RankOrder, isnull(A.PreviousTarget, 0) PreviousTarget
from tblEmployee e 
               left join 
                         (
                             select EmpCode, CurrentTarget, CreatedDate,RankOrder,T.PreviousTarget 
                             from (
                                      Select EmpCode, CurrentTarget, CreatedDate,PreviousTarget, Rank() over (partition by EmpCode order by CreatedDate desc) RankOrder
                                      From tbl_Target
                                  ) T WHERE RankOrder=1
                         ) A on A.empCode = e.tm_emp_id
```

When displaying the CurrentTarget and the PreviousTarget, since they will be `NULL` for employees with no target, you can make use of the [ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function and return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need all records from tblEmployee, and only those that match from tblTarget...

In addition for every employee that do not have matching Target, `A.PreviousTarget` will be `NULL`, so you need to manage it using `ISNULL` function.

So to achieve this, you only need to change the `Left Join` in your query to `Right Join`, or rewrite it as below:

```
SELECT 
    EmpCode,
    E.TM_Name, 
    CurrentTarget, 
    CreatedDate,RankOrder,
    ISNULL(A.PreviousTarget,0) AS PreviousTarget -- <==== ATTENTION
FROM  tblEmployee AS E LEFT JOIN -- <==== ATTENTION
(
   SELECT 
       EmpCode, 
       CurrentTarget, 
       CreatedDate,
       RankOrder,
       T.PreviousTarget 
   FROM (
          SELECT
              EmpCode, 
              CurrentTarget, 
              CreatedDate,
              PreviousTarget,
              Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS RankOrder
           FROM tbl_Target
         )AS T 
    WHERE RankOrder=1
)AS A
ON A.EmpCode=E.TM_Emp_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't see where the CreatedDate and RankOrder are taken from when no record exists, this will show 0 for CurrentTarget and PreviousTarget for such records:

```
WITH
  T (EmpCode, CurrentTarget, CreatedDate, PreviousTarget, RankOrder) AS (
    SELECT EmpCode, CurrentTarget, CreatedDate, PreviousTarget
      , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
    FROM tbl_Target
  )
SELECT 
  E.TM_Emp_Id,
  E.TM_Name,
  ISNULL(T.CurrentTarget, 0),
  T.CreatedDate,
  T.RankOrder,
  ISNULL(T.PreviousTarget, 0)
FROM tblEmployee E 
  LEFT JOIN T ON E.TM_Emp_Id = T.EmpCode AND T.RankOrder = 1
```